# Combine rows while importing txt file if they don't meet a condition

Tags: python

```html
ROW_ID|Quote Number|Status|Status Reason ADT|Name|Account|Alias ADT|......etc 418 Columns
```

I have a large pipe delimitated file, Approx 2 million rows (2gs). The file is supposed to have 418 columns (|) per row, however, many of the rows have been unnecessarily split causing problems when importing the data.

When importing I would like to combine rows until the count of pipes in the subsequent row == 418.

Most of the problems occur at column 90 and are followed by a row with 328. Others are split at 90, followed by a few rows of 0 and then 328. Ideally, all of these rows would be combined into one.

[For example, the highlighted rows should be combined into one (rows with 0 still contain information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMOrg.png)

[I thought about appending the incorrect rows to a list, and then combining them, but at 1 second per row, this would take approximately 26 days to complete.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGCan.png)

I also tried to combine the lines before appending, but am afraid I will run into the same efficiency problems.

```python
%%time

correct = []
incorrect = []

with open('C:/Users/jschlajo/Desktop/export_all_quotes_compass.txt', 'r') as fh:
    for index, line in enumerate(fh):
        if index<20:
            if line.count('|')!=418:
                incorrect.append(line)
```

Comment: I suggest that you use the `csv` package. You can specify what delimiter to use.

Comment: Yes, I am using import csv package, and I can specify the Pipe delimiter. The problem is not all of the rows contain the correct number of delimiters.

Comment: Can you give an example of a few rows of input? Are there any text fields that contain new line characters?

Comment: Install 2 EBKs, KP, install HUBs at teller and Access bar , use HUBs removed from Tellers. TCR connection . OT Labor

Comment: That is the end of a line that was  cut off. Wish I could post more examples but the information is sensitive, there are no \n

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the example line.

Answer (score 1):

It turns on when you use Enumerate it takes drastically longer. I removed that part of my code, appended all of the problem rows to a list. It took 34 seconds Vs the 26 days I anticipated. Then I joined the entire list, and split the list every 418 pipes

```html
correct = []
incorrect = []

with open('C:/Users/jschlajo/Desktop/export_all_quotes_compass.txt', 'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if line.count('|')==418:
                correct.append(line)
        if line.count('|')!=418:
                incorrect.append(line)
                
                
test_1 = ' '.join(incorrect)                
i = iter(test_1.split('|'))


span = 418
words = test_1.split("|")
combined = ["|".join(words[i:i+span]) for i in range(0, len(words), span)]
```

Comment: Just a note for the future, please do not post images of code. Instead, paste it into your question/answer and format it as a code block.